Can I substitute a 4 wire fan capacitor for a 3 wire one and not use the third capacitor section?
One section of a 3 wire 4/4.5uF fan capacitor is bad and I have searched all over on line for a replacement (18 year old (Craftmade).  Can I substitute a 4 wire 4/4.5/5uF capacitor and just not use the third section?

dual capacitor, one is the start and the other one is run.

Yes, you can use a 4 wire 4/4.5/5uF fan capacitor instead of a 3 wire one with 4/4.5uF. The extra wire gives you more options. You can connect it like this: use the first two sections (4uF and 4.5uF) and leave the third section (5uF) unused. It should work fine for your 18-year-old Craftmade fan.
